# What is a usecase for the fabric-kafka and fabric-order containers in same network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I can see there are 3 types of orderer. When I  deploy  a  fabric-network  up to 2 types are used.

https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-orderer/
https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-kafka/

https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-ca-orderer/

The order documentation describes usage

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/orderer/README.md

but I do not expect to see fabric-orderer  and fabric-kafka containers in  a  fabric network.

What  am I  misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The architecture for Hyperledger Fabric allows for multiple types of ordering services.  At the heart of the architecture is a common atomic broadcast interface.

The orderer interfaces are implemented in the orderer executable which is packaged as the fabric-orderer Docker image.

There are two configuration modes for the orderer:

1) Solo - this is a standalone, single process orderer primarily for use during development and test (although nothing would stop someone from using it for production - it would just not be fault tolerant)

2) Kafka - this leverages Kafka as the "consensus" mechanism to make multiple orderer processes crash fault tolerant and order transactions.  In this case, multiple orderer processes communicate with a Kafka cluster which ensures that each orderer process receives transactions and generates blocks in the same order.  The orderer process (or fabric-orderer containers) communicate with a Kafka cluster (which can be run using the fabric-kafka and fabric-zookeeper Docker images).

Comment: OK, so   the orderer process ( fabric-orderer containers) communicate with a Kafka cluster (which can be run using the fabric-kafka and fabric-zookeeper Docker images).    

This means I  would  expect  to see both. Thank you.

Comment: You got it and not a problem