# Using kafka configuration in hyperledger composer setup

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I just want to know whether we can use hyperledger composer in the scenario where there are multiple orderers deployed in kafka configuration ?

Comment: Unless something has changed in the fabric-node-sdk,  In Hyperledger Composer (0.19.x with Fabric 1.1) you can only define a single orderer in the Composer connection profile (even though the stanza is defined as an array), even in a kafka setup/cluster as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652528/what-is-a-usecase-for-the-fabric-kafka-and-fabric-order-containers-in-same-netwo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyperledger Composer can be used against any fabric network setup. So it will work with both a Solo Orderer setup as well as a kafka configured setup. However as noted in the comment there is a limitation in that although you can define multiple orderers in the connection profile, only the first one in the list is used to interact with an orderer.

A new feature that went into the fabric-node-sdk 1.2 allows it to try other orderers in the list if it fails to send proposals to an orderer.
When Composer is able to work with a fabric 1.2 setup then this feature will be available.